# Resizing of a header/div in a website through css in wordpress

Tags: customization, css, headers

How can I resize the mentioned header/div of my WordPress website? I have already tried it through checking the div name by going into Inspect Element but it is not working. One thing more the size changes and it gets normal when I click on the customize option. Please help me. I have attached a picture

Link for the screenshot of the webpage
https://ibb.co/KXVyyML

Comment: Clear cache after adding the CSS

Comment: Okay i will try that and let you know

Comment: Always do a Force Refresh after making CSS changes. Ctrl + F5 on PC or Cmd + Shift + R on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to give a solution without a link. 
In general you would add a max-width value to the div that is your header.
For example let's imagine that the following code is your header code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menuHolder">
        HERE WILL BE OTHER CODES SUCH AS YOUR MENU
    </div>
</div>
```

Then to make your entire header smaller in width you can use this CSS:

```
#header {
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or you can apply the same CSS to the inner div such as this:

```
#menuHolder {
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```